# IntelliJ IDEA Github plugin for Github enterprise

Tags: github, intellij-idea

We use an enterprise instance of github in my company. The instance is hosted on `https://github.company.com`.

In the Github plugin, if I enter 'github.company.com', and my login credentials, then select 'Test', the plugin reports failure for the given credentials.

I know the credentials are correct. I've also tried 'https://github.company.com' for the host (though I've read somewhere that https is assumed on this plugin), with the same failure.

I use IntelliJ IDEA 12.0.4, and the bundled Github plugin. IDEA is being run on a Linux Mint 14 workstation (if that makes any difference).

Any ideas (no pun)?

Thanks

Comment: See if [this comment](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-101925#comment=27-452085) helps.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Left the company a little later, so never progressed this and no company I've been with since has used GitHub (Bitbucket and GitLab, primarily since then). If CrazyCoder's link helps, please give him credit